# magento orders timezone issue

Tags: timezone

Magento is storing orders in UTC time, however I'd like it to be ETC. My server time is ETC already, however I believe I need to set it in magento as well. Where can I do it? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Timezone from Admin. Goto Magento Admin :

> System => Configuration => General => Locale Options =>Timezone

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Actually it is set to Eastern Standard Time(USA/New York)

Comment: Is it resolve your issue ?